# Prefs why QI the branch?

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon, preferences

Hi all I'm trying to hook up preference listeners and stuff, but in the codes I'm finding out there they are QI'ing it, i have no idea why. Do you guys know why? These are examples of code im seeing:

```
this._branch = Services.prefs.getBranch(branch_name);
this._defaultBranch = Services.prefs.getDefaultBranch(branch_name);
this._branch.QueryInterface(Ci.nsIPrefBranch2);
```

in the above they don't QI the _defaultBranch, why's that? and why qi `nsIPrefBranch2` why not just `nsIPrefBranch`?

this code snippet is from xul school: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Adding_preferences_to_an_extension

```
 this.prefs = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/preferences-service;1"]
     .getService(Components.interfaces.nsIPrefService)
     .getBranch("extensions.stockwatcher2.");
 this.prefs.QueryInterface(Components.interfaces.nsIPrefBranch);
 this.prefs.addObserver("", this, false);
```

here they QI to just `nsIPrefBranch`

i'm so confused by all the methods which way is the right way?

Comment: ok i think its because it enables you to use `addObserver`, but how come if we `addObserver` to the `_branch` any change on `_defualtBranch` triggers that observrer? I don't get why they don't QI `_defaultBranch`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`nsIPrefBranch2` is a legacy interface that these days inherits `nsIPrefBranch` but is *empty* otherwise. It is only still there so that "old" code that was written in the Firefox 3.x days and therefore uses `nsIPrefBranch2` does not break; otherwise it would have been removed already.
So any new code that isn't supposed to also run on Firefox 3.x has no need to QI to `nsIPrefBranch2`.

(BTW: it is essentially the same story for `nsIFile` vs. `nsILocalFile`).

However, once upon a time, `nsIPrefBranch2` actually [added `addObserver` and `removeObserver`](http://hg.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/file/0fba4d8f69c5/modules/libpref/public/nsIPrefBranch2.idl) (which now are part of `nsIPrefBranch`). So to use `addObserver` you needed to those QI calls. IIRC, the reason to use a new interface instead of extending the old one was ABI (binary) compatibility. Since Firefox 4 there are no guarantees for binary compatibility between major versions, so the two interfaces got merged.

`getBranch().QueryInterfac(Ci.nsIPrefBranch)` is entirely pointless. My guess would be that the code used to say `nsIPrefBranch2` at some point and the author did an automated `nsIPrefBranch2` -> `nsIPrefBranch` rewrite later...

So, to repeat:
New code does not need to QI to `nsIPrefBranch2`, and certainly there is no need to QI `nsIPrefBranch` to `nsIPrefBranch` again.

I'd re-write your examples as:

```
this._branch = Services.prefs.getBranch(branch_name); // Already returns nsIPrefBranch
this._defaultBranch = Services.prefs.getDefaultBranch(branch_name); // Already returns nsIPrefBranch
```

and:

```
this.prefs = Services.prefs.getBranch("extensions.stockwatcher2.");
this.prefs.addObserver("", this, false);
```

PS: It appears the `QI(Ci.nsIPrefBranch)` code was indeed an [automatic rewrite](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Adding_preferences_to_an_extension%24compare?to=492835&from=340849). I removed the QI call now.

Comment: Oh btw since what version was `nsIPrefs2` merged to `nsIPrefs`?

Comment: Sorry, should have mentioned this. [MDN says](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Tech/XPCOM/Reference/Interface/nsIPrefBranch2) Gecko 13.